# How to determine if an equation is linear or quadratic relationship?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

I have an equation of the form
$y= \frac{v}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x}$. I can rewrite it as $y= vx^{-2} - x^{-1}$. I don't know if it's quadratic. Any suggestions on what this relationship would like?

Comment: You can look at it as a quadratic dependence on $u=1/x$, or a linear dependence on $u=1/x$ and $v=1/x^2$ together.

Comment: @Ian Can you please expand on the latter? I can't quite see how it would be y = mx + c

Comment: It's $Y=a u + b v$ for constants $a,b$. (This is how polynomial fits with given exponents are implemented numerically.)

Answer (score 1):

$y=\frac{V}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}$ is not quadratic. Quadradic equations have the form
$y=ax^2+bx+c$. Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you can solve for $y$ as such:
$$y=\frac{V-x}{x^2}$$
so that
$$yx^2=V-x$$

Make a column containing values for $y_n\times x_n^2$ and another for $x_n$. You can create a linear regression from the resulting data. The slope should be $-1$, while the y-intercept should equal $V$.

While simple, this may not be the best approach. There are ways to fit data to arbitrary equations like yours without linearizing it. Google "curve fitting in Excel" for some options.

EDIT: Your equation is also quadratic in $x^{-1}$. Form a quadratic regression of $y$ vs. $1/x$ and see what happens.

Comment: To confirm the equation in itself is not linear right? To linearize it without the method you suggested, I'd have to take logs, right?

Comment: Your equation is not linear or quadratic in $x$, but it is quadratic in $1/x$. Taking logs won't help you much in this case.

Comment: +1 but the parts about regression seem unnecessary